# How to find Devanagari fonts

Tags: fonts, indic

I am trying out different ways of using LaTeX with Devanagari script, and I have come across some examples that have the following lines of code:

```
\documentclass{article}

% The fontspec package provides a nice interface to font loading.
\usepackage{fontspec}

% standard packages for XeLaTeX
\usepackage{xunicode}
\usepackage{xltxtra}

% The polyglossia package lets us easily use several languages.
\usepackage{polyglossia}

\newfontfamily\devanagarifont[Script=Devanagari]{Nakula}
\newfontfamily\englishfont[Script=Latin]{XITS}

\setmainlanguage{sanskrit}
\setotherlanguages{english}
```

I run the code with XeLaTeX but it says it can't find the "Nakula" font (or the "XITS" font, for that matter).  So, my question is, where do I look to see which fonts are currently installed, and how do I find the "Nakula" font?  I searched for it on CTAN with no results.

Comment: I just type Devanagari Nakula fonts free for Google and She gives me http://bombay.indology.info/software/fonts/devanagari/

Comment: Thank you!  And where do I put them to be able to use them with LaTeX?

Comment: If you are in windows --->C:\Windows\fonts

Comment: http://www.fontspring.com/support/installing/how-do-i-install-fonts-on-my-mac or http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201722

Comment: https://fonts.google.com/?subset=devanagari — as of this writing it lists 44 Devanagari fonts. (To install on Mac: download any of those and double-click it to open in `Font Book`, then click on "Install font". It will get placed in `~/Library/Fonts`.)